# Requiring ui.bootstrap when using Browserify

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have had some trouble trying to inject a reference to AngularUI's ui.bootstrap service. I am using browserify so I cannot just add the script to the base html file. When I try and call angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']); I get the following error message:

```
Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name
or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the
dependencies as the second argument.
```

What does it mean 'second argument'? If I have to use import/require where should I put the `.min.js` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`second argument` refers to the second argument to `angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);` It's simply telling you that a module named `ui.bootstrap` was never defined.

You really should post your code to get a better answer. But, this is what you typically want to do with browserify:

```
// require angular
var angular = require('angular');
require('angular-ui-bootstrap');  // no need to create a variable

angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']); // all done
```

As long as `angular-ui-bootstrap` had been installed to your project (`npm install --save angular-ui-bootstrap`), this should work.